# Standardization of layers formula

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, normalize

I am building a suitability map in which I have different vector layers and raster data, I have converted all my vector layers into raster and I am using these two formulas to normalize the distribution and then standardize into a common scale from 1 to 0.

Theses are the formulas that I am using: Raster calculator in ArcGIS, (x - mean) / stdv --> ( x - min(x) ) / ( max(x) - min(x) )

I just want to check if this is a good approach to standardize my layers? or what is the best approach to normalizing different nature layers to then proceed with weighted overlay analysis?

Comment: If a given variable is non-gaussian the deviation from the mean divided by the standard deviation will be incorrect. If your intent is just to scale to the same data range than your second approach will work for positive data. For weights a common approach is `x / sum(x)`. All that said and done make sure that you use a fuzzy sum to combine the data. Here is a previous related answer  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50169/how-to-standardize-raster-output-from-0-to-100-using-raster-algebra/50173#50173

Comment: There is also this answer that shows how to recenter the data https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194814/rescale-raster-in-r/194838#194838

Comment: How can I know if my data is normally distributed in ArcGis? Some of my layers are polygons with number values representing income index per commune, with values from 1-6 that I have transformed into raster

Comment: There are statistical tests to evaluate if your data is distributed close to normal. I don't know if they are available in ArcGis. A rough way is to look at the histogram of the layers or data (it's the same foundation). If they are bell-shaped in the center, they tend to be normal.

Comment: You can also compare the central tendency statistics, to tend to normality the average and the median must have similar values. ArcGis in its statistics tools should evaluate normality, look in the normality test aids.

Comment: Another aspect, which you should be careful about, is the type of variable you are using, which can be quantitative or qualitative. Quantitative variables, in turn, can have various forms, nominal, ordinal, scale. Qualitative variables are treated by assigning values, indices, but this does not make them quantitative. I recommend that you investigate these aspects of statistics and data management before continuing.

Comment: You cannot transform a nominal variable in the same way that you would a random variable. As far as normally distributed data, you would not expect a normal distribution with nominal data and, with this type of analysis, i would just assume that random variables are not normal. You could actually confound results of a suitability analysis by re-entering you data. You want to retain the shape of your distributions when overlaying with other data so, normality is really a moot point. Also, be weary of synthizing qualitative and quantitative data.

Comment: Thank you for all the input, I understand the different types of data I can have, which I do in my case. So my question is how should I proceed in order to perform the suitability analysis correctly? Most of the research papers I've read just state that they perform a standardization of variables (discrete and continuous data) with this formula: ( x - min(x) ) / ( max(x) - min(x) ) and that's it, they don't explain in depth any further steps. That's why I'm looking for guidance with this topic.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to give a direct answer, it depends on your data, the first thing is to be clear about the basics.

The first thing you should do is an exploratory data analysis (ESDA)

- **The first formula**: (x - mean) / stdv is a standardization, that is, you will bring your layer values to a scale defined by the standard deviation and centered around the mean.
  Your new values will represent how far around the mean that value is.

In this case you are assuming that the mean and standard deviation are a good descriptor of the distribution of your data. This is ideal, if your data has a normal distribution.
This is true even if your data deviates from the normal distribution, due to the Cheviched theorem and the Central Limit theorem.

- **The second formula** ( x - min(x) ) / ( max(x) - min(x) ): you are simply scaling the values to a range of 0 to 1.
- If you want to have the benefits of standardization but some of your layers have very irregular distributions you can consider a **third option**, standardizing by considering the median (instead of the mean) and the interquartile range (instead of the standard deviation).

This approach tends to fit better with any distribution.
The transformed value will represent in units the interquartile range that is so far from the median.