# Rescale NDVI (-1:1) to 0-255 using R

Tags: raster, r, ndvi

I am trying to rescale my NDVI band (-1:1) to 0:255. I am trying to follow the approach in this post: [Rescale raster in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194814/rescale-raster-in-r) , but I am getting NA values.

```
# my ndvi

ndvi

class      : RasterLayer 
band       : 5  (of  5  bands)
dimensions : 10120, 15200, 153824000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent     : 747400, 751200, 4309040, 4311570  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : D:/a4_v21/airborne_imagery/Area_2019/GeoTIFF_025/0796_2-5_2019_NDVI.tif 
names      : X0796_2.5_2019_NDVI.5 
values     : -1, 0.8059701  (min, max)
```

I define the rescale function and I try to rescale the raster:

```
rescale <- function(x, x.min = NULL, x.max = NULL, new.min = 0, new.max = 1) {
  if(is.null(x.min)) x.min = min(x)
  if(is.null(x.max)) x.max = max(x)
  new.min + (x - x.min) * ((new.max - new.min) / (x.max - x.min))
}

ndvi <- rescale(ndvi, x.min=-1, x.max=1, new.min=0, new.max=255)
```

I get the following results:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10120, 15200, 153824000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent     : 747400, 751200, 4309040, 4311570  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpiu6LVs/raster/r_tmp_2021-01-23_222619_14736_96336.grd 
names      : X0796_2.5_2019_NDVI.5 
values     : NA, NA  (min, max)
```

How can I fix this error? I can't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Try the `rescaleImage` function in the RStoolbox package.

Comment: Thank you a lot @JeffreyEvans. It works perfectly using `rescaleImage` function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SOLVED** using `rescaleImage()` function in RStoolbox:

```
library(RStoolbox)

ndvi <- rescaleImage(x= ndvi, xmin = -1, xmax = 1, ymin=0, ymax=255)
```

Now I get the expected results:

```
ndvi

class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10120, 15200, 153824000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent     : 747400, 751200, 4309040, 4311570  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0, 230.2612  (min, max)
```

Comment: The RStoolbox is no longer available on CRAN. The code originally presented works just fine. The issue is that there are NA's in the data so `min` and `max` need a `na.rm=TRUE` argument so that results are not also NA as you were getting in the resulting raster. Now, of course the call would be `terra::app()` replacing `raster::calc`